# why do all planes hold position when Air Force 1 is taxiing?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport

Why does everyone hold in position when Air Force One is just taxiing? This can cause a delay that could cascade to other airports.

Comment: Because the PotUS' security detail is paranoid.

Comment: Since AF1 movements are generally planned, airlines do have a chance to take steps to minimize delays - They probably still occur, but can be reduced.

Answer (score 12):

No doubt security has a lot to do with it. With only one vehicle supposed to move on the airport premises, everything else that moves can be easily spotted and classified as a potential threat, and resources dispatched to handle it.

If there are dozens of other aircraft and hundreds of cars and trucks moving around, this gets a lot harder.